# Как выровнять div элементы в 1 строку

Tags: html, css

Столкнулась с проблемой, почему то элементы не хотят становиться в 1 строку в header. Не хочу использовать bootstrap пока сама не разберусь в css. Как можно это исправить?
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/header.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="hederStyle">
        <div class="borderStyle">
            <div class="positionStyle">
                <h1 class="titleStyle">Pet Shop</h1>
                <h1 class="titleStyle">Pet Shop</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: "FontYou";
    src: url(/fonts/acmesa.TTF) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }
 #newfont {
    font-family: 'FontYou';
}
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background: #F3E7D7;
}

.hederStyle{
    padding: 20px;
}

.borderStyle{
    border-bottom: 8px solid #C7B65E;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.titleStyle{
    color: #D87E9F;
    font-size: 60pt;
    font-family: FontYou;
}

.imgStyle{
    width: 450px;
}

.positionStyle{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сменить `display`

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #F3E7D7;
}

.hederStyle {
  padding: 20px;
}

.borderStyle {
  border-bottom: 8px solid #C7B65E;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.titleStyle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #D87E9F;
  font-size: 60pt;
}

.imgStyle {
  width: 450px;
}

.positionStyle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="hederStyle">
  <div class="borderStyle">
    <div class="positionStyle">
      <h1 class="titleStyle">Pet Shop</h1>
      <h1 class="titleStyle">Pet Shop</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>

</main>
```

по умолчанию `<h1>` блоковый тип и растягиваеться на всю длинну страницы. Можете использовать `<span>`

Comment: ```.positionStyle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 20px;
}```
Мне от такую штуку подсказали и усе заработало